# Having different appearance of radio buttons within same group

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few groups of radio buttons. I would like to change appearance of only few radio buttons in a group and rest as just like radio buttons. Is there some javascript or jquery for it...

```
<div id = "radio1">
<p>Do you like to walk?</p>
<input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp1"/> Yes <br />
<input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp1"/> No <br /> 
<input type="radio" value="c" name="radgrp1"/> Clear <br />
</div>

<div id = "radio2">
<p>Would you prefer to walk without effort?</p>
<input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp2"/> Yes <br />
<input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp2"/> No <br /> 
<input type="radio" value="c" name="radgrp2"/> Clear <br />
</div>
```

In the above code I would prefer third radio option in each  to appear as a normal button while keeping the first and second as radio buttons. Looking for a solution that works in Internet Explorer 6. Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Got a solution at w3schools while reading about *label tag*  and  *css display property* 
For the third radio button in each div, I assigned it an id {rad[0], rad[1]} in this case and used label to point to that id. What comes after (Label) "for" is the "id" of html element we are assigning a label to.

```
<div id = "radio1">
<p>Do you like to walk?</p>
<input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp1"/> Yes <br />
<input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp1"/> No <br /> 
<input type="radio" value="c" name="radgrp1"id="rad[0]" style="display:none;"/>
<label for="rad[0]"><input type ="button"value="Clear"/></label>
</div>

<div id = "radio2">
<p>Would you prefer to walk without effort?</p>
<input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp2"/> Yes <br />
<input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp2"/> No <br /> 
<input type="radio" value="c" name="radgrp2"id="rad[1]" style="display:none;"/>
<label for="rad[1]"><input type ="button"value="Clear"/></label>
</div>
```

I used buttons as Label for radio buttons, but images too can be added the same way. In place of

```
<input type ="button"value="Clear"/>,
```

use `<img src="yourimage.png">`between the opening and closing label tags.

Comment: You can do it using pseudo-elements, but that won't help with zombie browsers. http://www.andreapinchi.it/how-to-style-radio-buttons-with-pure-css Don't forget to use labels for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can  change appearance of only few radio buttons in a group and rest as just like radio buttons.

```
      radio=document.getElementByName("radgrp1");
```

and then apply your setting to any of radio button

```
      radio[0]------>for first radio buton
      radio[1]------>for second
      radio[2]------>for third
```

Comment: This is a good start on selection, but how would you restyle the elements as buttons?

Comment: document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style

Comment: Thanks pls explain in some detail.